# ListView dynamic datarow changing on scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android-recyclerview

I want to change the text and background color of the text view from "Not Uploaded" to "Uploading..." and want to change the background color as well. But when i click on the upload button it change the color and text of the selected view but it also make same changes to the last visible item+1. When I scroll through the list the change effect keep on shifting on other views as well. 
**[image: strong text]**

**Here is the code for my custom adapter getview function**

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = null;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fileview,parent,false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_file);
        TextView tv_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_fileDate);
        TextView tvFileSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFileSize);
        TextView tvFileStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUploadStatus);
        ImageView _img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_file);
        ImageView btnTrash = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnTrash);
        ImageView btnEdit = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        ImageView btnUpload = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);

        btnTrash.setOnClickListener(new myclickListener(context,files[position],position));
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new myclickListener(context,files[position],position));
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new myclickListener(context,files[position],position));



        int index = files[position].lastIndexOf(".");
        String file_extention = files[position].substring(index+1,files[position].length());
        file_extention=file_extention.toLowerCase();

        if(file_extention.equals("png"))
        {
            _img.setImageResource(images[0]);
        }
        else if(file_extention.equals("txt"))
        {
            _img.setImageResource(images[1]);
        }

        if(appPreferences.getUploadValue(files[position]).equals(statusUploaded))
        {
            tvFileStatus.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tvFileStatus.setText(statusUploaded);
            tvFileStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fileview2);
        }
        else if (appPreferences.getUploadValue(files[position]).equals(statusUploading)) {
            tvFileStatus.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tvFileStatus.setText(statusUploading);
            tvFileStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fileview3);
        }



        tv.setText(files[position]);
        tvFileSize.setText("Size:" + file_sizes[position]);
        tv_date.setText(file_dates[position]);

    }
    else
    {
        v=convertView;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: when you have only one if and else condition dont use else if. use 'else' instead. Try removing else if and insert else. Might solve your problem.

Comment: @DroidAks and what about if he need if condition ("txt") only ? or any non of them?

Comment: you should use ViewHolder

Comment: the problem with the list view is that if you only enter 'if' condition then it applies the color change for other views once you scroll the listview. There needs to be 'else' part so that it does not override the colors for other views once scrolled.

Comment: @DroidAks You are right ... I have changed the condition and now it's not shifting the changes to the other elements.. kindly suggest me what is the best way to temporarily change the list item on runtime that should change the messages to NotUploaded=>Uploading....=> Uploaded

Comment: @Survivor I will try it with viewHolder now... thank you bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use `ViewHolder` when implementing `ListView`. Refer [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: thank you bro... let me try this tutorial if it will work for me i will take your answer :)

Comment: I have used viewHolder + notifydatasetchanged() on my custom adapter to get my required effect .. thank you :)